# Implement intent method after clicking the notification (NotificationCompat.Builder)

Tags: java, android, firebase-notifications

I'm developing a notification method. it's working successfully. but how can I implement `Onclick` method to navigate a specific activity?

```
private void notification() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel channel=new NotificationChannel("n","n", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager=getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"n")
                .setContentText("Alert")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText("Check your fit Room Request");

        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat=NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        managerCompat.notify(999,builder.build());

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"n")
 .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
 .....
```